# Command object automatically added to model?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a controller method like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public String hello(UserForm user) {
    return "hello";
}
```

It receives some request parameters in the `UserForm` command object. But I have **not** written any code to add the object to the Model. Still, in the view `hello.jsp`, I'm able to access the data, like this:

```
Hello, ${userForm.name}!
```

Does it mean that Spring MVC adds command objects to the Model automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `@ModelAttribute` just to use a `Bean` as a parameter.

You'll need to use `@ModelAttribute` or `model.addAttribute()` to load default data into your model - for example from a database.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Spring controllers in the real world accept a lot of different types of parameters - Path variables, URL parameters, request headers, request body and sometimes even the entire HTTP Request object. This provides a flexible mechanism to create APIs. Spring is really good at parsing these parameters in to Java types as long as there is an ObjectMapper (like Jackson) configured to take care of the de-serialization.

The RequestMappingHandlerAdapter makes sure the arguments of the method are resolved from the HttpServletRequest.

> Spring model data created prior to (or during) the handler method
>   execution gets copied to the HttpServletRequest before the next view
>   is rendered.

By now, Spring has processed the HTTP request and it creates the ModelAndView object from the method’s return value. Also, note that you are not required to return a ModelAndView instance from a controller method. You may return a view name, or a ResponseEntity or a POJO that will be converted to a JSON response etc.

```
ServletInvocableHandlerMethod invocableMethod 
  = createInvocableHandlerMethod(handlerMethod);
if (this.argumentResolvers != null) {
    invocableMethod.setHandlerMethodArgumentResolvers(
      this.argumentResolvers);
}
if (this.returnValueHandlers != null) {
    invocableMethod.setHandlerMethodReturnValueHandlers(
      this.returnValueHandlers);
}
```

The returnValueHandlers object is a composite of HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler objects. There are also a lot of different value handlers that can process the result of your method to create ModelAndViewobject expected by the adapter.

Then, it has to render the HTML page that the user will see in the browser. It does that based on the model and the selected view encapsulated in the ModelAndView object.

Now, at this stage, the view gets access to the `userForm` (as in your example above) from the `request scope`.